# preg_match if tabulator at end of string

Tags: php, preg-match

How to check if there is a tab at the end of a string? Which pattern works? I tried `/\+t$/` but i get "There is NO tab at the end of the string" even though there is a tabulator at the end.

```
<?php
$text = "Come to the dark side. We have cookies    ";
$pattern = "/\+t$/";

if(preg_match($pattern , $text)) 
{
   echo "There is a tab at the end of the string";
} 
else 
{
   echo "There is NO tab at the end of the string";
}
?>
```

Comment: `$pattern = "/\t$/"` ? - I use this site a lot to test my PHP regex's before putting them in code. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks this works. I even tested your code before on a website and i just realised that it did not worked because the websites code simulator does not recgonize tabs -.- In future i will use your website, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `/\+t$/` matches a `+` sign followed by character `t` at the end of a string.

I guess you want :

- `/\t$/` : a tabulation at the end of the string
- or `/\t+$/` : one or more tabulations at the end